# How to access a WhatsApp template on Twilio using Python?

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have created multiple WhatsApp templates, but I am unsure of how to access them from the Twilio backend. Is there a way to access these templates?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by access? Reading them programmatically or sending a message based on the templates?

Comment: @IObert Sending messages based on the templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send pre-approved template with the following code:

```py
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
import json


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
                              content_sid='HXXXXXXXXX',
                              from_='MGXXXXXXXX',
                              content_variables=json.dumps({
                                  '1': 'Name'
                              }),
                              to='whatsapp:+18551234567'
                          )

print(message.sid)
```

Go [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-editor#maincontent) for the full docs.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Never found it in the documentation at that time. Once again, thank you and really appreciate that!